# Echo from two tables and two ids in array

Tags: php, sql, arrays, echo

I have a list of products, which can have different properties (color, size etc).
Properties are saved in my db as property table in the following form:
[image]

While the chosen properties get saved to each individual product in the form of parentid.id, for example this 2nd entry (id 4) has blue color property.

[image]

But what I'm trying to achieve now, is to **echo these** selected values on the product, the same way they are saved, so:
Parent Title - This id (child)  or based on example: Color - Blue.

But I can't figure out, how to. I've tried imploding the properties array, but then I only get the last part, so only 2 from 1.2 and echoes Blue. I would need both, 1 and 2 (Color-blue).

It's kind of hard to explain, but if anyone understood at least a bit what I would need and has any idea how this could be done, I would be very grateful for any tips and hints.

Thanks in advance ;)

Comment: Just to clarify, 1.2 means the row  in property table that has id 2 and id_parent 1?

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Comment: you need to split the value from php first and then create appropriate query from it. Make sense?

Comment: It does, but the first part on splitting the values is confusing me, I can't find an easy way how.

Comment: Show us your php code that is splitting it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do to make this work:

1. Select your properties from db
2. Parse them into groups (explode by ',' to work with them one at a time)
3. Build an array of parent/children by parsing the groups

   (ex: groupings = [
       parent1 => [child1, child2, etc],
       parent2 => [child1, child2, etc],
   ])

   a. loop through each group
   b. explode by '.' to get the parent/child pairing
   c. put into array
4. Build your where clause
   a. Parents: where (id in (parent1, parent2, etc))
   b. Children: (parent = parent AND id IN (child1, child2, etc))